# Select next to last tr

Tags: jquery

I'd like to be grab the next to last TR in a table.

```
$("#TableID tr:last")
```

gets the very last one, is there some way I can get the TR prior to that one?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When a negative index is specified for eq, it starts counting backwards from the end.

> **.eq( -index )**
>
> **-index** An integer indicating the position of the element, counting backwards from the last element in the set.

```
$('#TableID tr').eq(-2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you could do it with the [.slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method:

```
$('#TableID tr').slice(-2, -1).addClass('dark');
```

You can see it [in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/DAuq9/).

Comment: Cool...didn't know about that one.  +1

Answer (score 1):

The selector is a string.  You can build out the selector string using a combination of the nth-child function and the .length property, or you can get all tr children and pick out the 2nd to last item with get().

```
var selector = "#TableID tr";
var second_to_last = $(selector).length - 2; // using 2 because it's 0 based
$(selector).get(second_to_last);
```